# NHibernate SaveOrUpdate Repository does not Update but Save Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, asp.net-web-api, s#arp-architecture

I have two Controllers that call the same CommandHandler for SaveOrUpdate.  One of the Controller is the normal MVC **Controller** while the other one is a WebAPI **ApiController**.  Both works fine in Save but on Update it only works for the normal MVC controller not on the **ApiController**.

I checked the ViewModel coming from the ApiController and its populating exactly the same as the normal Controller.  I also did some tracing on the database and it seems that it does not run the Update Query it just disregards the submitted data.

Here is the code

```
public class SaveOrUpdateRequestNameChangeCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<SaveOrUpdateRequestNameChangeCommand>
{
    private readonly INHibernateRepository<RequestStatus> requestStatusRepository;

    private readonly INHibernateRepository<RequestNameChange> requestNameChangeRepository;

    public SaveOrUpdateRequestNameChangeCommandHandler(
        INHibernateRepository<RequestStatus> requestStatusRepository,
        INHibernateRepository<RequestNameChange> requestNameChangeRepository)
    {
        this.requestStatusRepository = requestStatusRepository;
        this.requestNameChangeRepository = requestNameChangeRepository;
    }

    public void Handle(SaveOrUpdateRequestNameChangeCommand command)
    {           
        var requestNameChange = command.RequestNameChangeId.HasValue
            ? requestNameChangeRepository.Get(command.RequestNameChangeId.Value)
            : new RequestNameChange();

        requestNameChange.Username = command.Username;
        requestNameChange.OriginalFirstName = command.OriginalFirstName;
        requestNameChange.OriginalLastName = command.OriginalLastName;
        requestNameChange.NewFirstName = command.NewFirstName;
        requestNameChange.NewLastName = command.NewLastName;
        requestNameChange.EffectiveDate = command.EffectiveDate;
        requestNameChange.NewEmailAddress = command.NewEmailAddress;
        requestNameChange.IsRetailUser = command.IsRetailUser;
        requestNameChange.SpecialRequirements = command.SpecialRequirements;
        requestNameChange.Notes = command.Notes;
        requestNameChange.ServiceDeskId = command.ServiceDeskId;
        requestNameChange.ServiceDeskUrl = command.ServiceDeskUrl;
        if (command.RequestStatusId != null)
            requestNameChange.RequestStatus = requestStatusRepository.Get(command.RequestStatusId.Value);
        requestNameChange.DateCreated = command.DateCreated;
        requestNameChange.CreatedBy = command.CreatedBy;

        requestNameChangeRepository.SaveOrUpdate(requestNameChange);

        command.RequestNameChangeId = requestNameChange.Id;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and this is making me crazy for the past couple of days.

Here is the values coming from the normal **Controller**

[image]

and this is the value coming from the **ApiController**

[image]

As you can see they are exactly identical apart from the CreatedBy (*dont worry about this I did made this identical as well on my tests*) but they one from the ApiController does not update the values.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**--------- UPDATE ---------**

Here is the codes for my **Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[Transaction]
public ActionResult SaveOrUpdate(RequestNameChangesViewModel viewModel, [DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var command = new SaveOrUpdateRequestNameChangeCommand(
                        viewModel.RequestNameChangeId,
                        viewModel.Username,
                        viewModel.OriginalFirstName,
                        viewModel.OriginalLastName,
                        viewModel.NewFirstName,
                        viewModel.NewLastName,
                        viewModel.EffectiveDate,
                        viewModel.NewEmailAddress,
                        viewModel.IsRetailUser,
                        viewModel.SpecialRequirements,
                        viewModel.Notes,
                        viewModel.ServiceDeskId,
                        viewModel.ServiceDeskUrl,
                        viewModel.RequestStatusId,
                        viewModel.DateCreated,
                        viewModel.CreatedBy
                        );

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            commandProcessor.Process(command);
            viewModel.RequestNameChangeId = command.RequestNameChangeId;
        }
    }

    var result = new[] { viewModel }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState);

    return Json(result);
}
```

and this is the code for ApiController

```
// POST Api/<controller>
[Transaction]
public void Post(RequestNameChangesViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var command = new SaveOrUpdateRequestNameChangeCommand(
            viewModel.RequestNameChangeId,
            viewModel.Username,
            viewModel.OriginalFirstName,
            viewModel.OriginalLastName,
            viewModel.NewFirstName,
            viewModel.NewLastName,
            viewModel.EffectiveDate,
            viewModel.NewEmailAddress,
            viewModel.IsRetailUser,
            viewModel.SpecialRequirements,
            viewModel.Notes,
            viewModel.ServiceDeskId,
            viewModel.ServiceDeskUrl,
            viewModel.RequestNameChangeId,
            viewModel.DateCreated,
            viewModel.CreatedBy
            );

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            commandProcessor.Process(command);
            viewModel.RequestNameChangeId = command.RequestNameChangeId;
        }
    }
}

// PUT Api/<controller>/5
[Transaction]
public void Put(int id, RequestNameChangesViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var command = new SaveOrUpdateRequestNameChangeCommand(
            viewModel.RequestNameChangeId,
            viewModel.Username,
            viewModel.OriginalFirstName,
            viewModel.OriginalLastName,
            viewModel.NewFirstName,
            viewModel.NewLastName,
            viewModel.EffectiveDate,
            viewModel.NewEmailAddress,
            viewModel.IsRetailUser,
            viewModel.SpecialRequirements,
            viewModel.Notes,
            viewModel.ServiceDeskId,
            viewModel.ServiceDeskUrl,
            viewModel.RequestNameChangeId,
            viewModel.DateCreated,
            viewModel.CreatedBy
            );

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            commandProcessor.Process(command);
            viewModel.RequestNameChangeId = command.RequestNameChangeId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a transaction wrapping each operation?

Comment: Thats the full code for the CommandHandler

Comment: does the MVC controller action perhaps have an attribute or action filters that create/commit a transaction around it? I've seen this before when I forget to use a transaction.

Comment: The only reason I can think of why this wouldn't work is because there is an attribute on the Mvc Controller that starts a transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After

```
requestNameChangeRepository.SaveOrUpdate(requestNameChange);
```

Just need to commit the changes so we add this piece of code.

```
requestNameChangeRepository.DbContext.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Similar issue with my using Fluent nHibernate and async API calls. Only had an issue with Update calls. My fix was to add:
Session.FlushAsync();

New code:
        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            Session.Update(entity);
            Session.FlushAsync();
        }

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like in the API method the id field is not used, shouldn't it set to the command object?

```
// PUT Api/<controller>/5
[Transaction]
public void Put(int id, RequestNameChangesViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var command = new SaveOrUpdateRequestNameChangeCommand(
            id,
            viewModel.Username,
            viewModel.OriginalFirstName,
            viewModel.OriginalLastName,
            viewModel.NewFirstName,
            viewModel.NewLastName,
            viewModel.EffectiveDate,
            viewModel.NewEmailAddress,
            viewModel.IsRetailUser,
            viewModel.SpecialRequirements,
            viewModel.Notes,
            viewModel.ServiceDeskId,
            viewModel.ServiceDeskUrl,
            viewModel.RequestNameChangeId,
            viewModel.DateCreated,
            viewModel.CreatedBy
            );

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            commandProcessor.Process(command);
            viewModel.RequestNameChangeId = command.RequestNameChangeId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try, requestNameChangeRepository.Session.Flush() after requestNameChangeRepository.SaveOrUpdate(requestNameChange); in the handler

Comment: It did not solve the issue but you gave me an idea that I should do something after requestNameChangeRepository.SaveOrUpdate(requestNameChange).  How I fixed it is instead of requestNameChangeRepository.Session.Flush() I tried requestNameChangeRepository.DbContext.CommitChanges();

Comment: You are welcome :), only thing I wondering is that the [Transaction] attribute should take care of that for you automatically and why that is not working